# Are there rings with uncountably many irreducible elements (prime elements, if in a PID)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ring-theory

I'm playing around and trying to construct rings with different numbers of irreducible elements, hence the above question.

Comment: Massive overkill: since being irreducible/prime is a first-order condition, take a nontrivial ultrapower of any ring with infinitely many irreducible elements.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  The term "first-order" is very common  but seems to be one used in different branches of mathematics with different meanings.  And ultrafilter is also unfamiliar to me. But if a a result in algebra can be proved from other branches I'd be happy to learn more about that branch.  Is that logic?

Comment: @PVanchinathan: Really? I don't recall this term ever being used with different meaning from the usual one. What meanings do you have in mind?

Comment: @tomasz  I had first order differential equation in mind. But that meaning of "first order" does not have any relevance here!

Comment: @PVanchinathan: Oh, right. But as you've said, this doesn't really make sense. Noah meant first order as in first order logic. The branch is model theory. It is right there in the wiki. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct

Comment: @tomasz Another usage is e.g. 'first order approximation'.

Comment: @lisyarus: But I've never heard of anyone using "first order condition" in this sense (besides the fact that it doesn't make sense in this context :) ).

Comment: @tomasz I do agree. My point is that the term "first-order" has indeed many different meanings, as opposed to your earlier comment.

Comment: @lisyarus: Sure. Point taken.

Answer (score 7):

Take a polynomial ring in a single variable $x$ with coefficients in real numbers (or complex numbers, what is important is the uncountablity). Then all degree one polynomials $(x-\alpha)$ are irreducible. Being degree 1 they cannot be products of lower degree polynomials!
This being a PID irreducible, prime are one and the same.

Comment: By extension, if you take any field (or even any domain, and *I think* any reduced ring) $F$, there will be $\lvert F\rvert+\aleph_0$ irreducible elements in $F[x]$.

Comment: @tomasz: Yes. Allowing $F$ to be other than fields will make possible to get irreducible elements as opposed to primes.